# Show/hide div on radiobutton selection in one one webpage and div on other in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have 2 webpages. In the 1st i hv 2 radiobuttons with images and a button. In the second aspx page i hv 2 divs. On selection of a radiobutton a particular div must be visible in second webpage and othr should hide. Am confused on how to work with these 2 webpages. Any suggestions ll be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You could just redirect to the second page passing a query string value indicating the 'state' the page should be in; for example, when your button is pressed and you've done processing everything else, do something like this:

```
Response.Redirect("/your/other/page?key=" + (myRadioButton.Checked ? "1" : "0"))
```

Then on your second page you can do something like this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["key"])) {
  if (Request.QueryString["key"] == "0") {
    // don't show some stuff
  } else if (Request.QueryString["key"] == "1") {
    // show some stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: The loop doesnt go inside the div. Think i am missing some functionality:(

Answer (score 0):

Store the radiobutton selection in some appropriate place and then on Page_Load read selection and hide div respectively.

Comment: div is in other aspx page..not on the same page where i have the radio button.